# Create a JSONB column with values collected from other columns in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, amazon-aurora

I have a Postgres table like

```
 UserID   EmailFlag    PrintFlag SomeOtherField
 12       1            0         yes
 34       0            1         somecomment
```

and in order to optimize SQL querying I want to employ JSONB derivative column like so:

```
 UserID   EmailFlag    PrintFlag SomeOtherField  JsonBDerivedColumn
 12       1            0         yes             {email: 1, print: 0 , comment: "yes"}
 34       0            1         somecomment     {email: 0, print: 1 , comment: "somecomment"}
```

How can I achieve populating `JsonBDerivedColumn` using Postgres SQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can't imagine which queries would be optimised by this duplication.

Comment: You might be looking for a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html).

Comment: @Bergi I have some complex queries and I am looking into optimizing these by using GIN indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the jsonb object from the other fields using the `jsonb_build_object` function :

```
jsonb_build_object('email', EmailFlag_field, 'print', PrintFlag_field, 'comment', SomeOtherField_field)
```

You can automatically populate the JsonBDerivedColumn column by trigger each time a row is inserted or updated in `your_table` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION T_Before_Insert_Update_your_table()  
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    NEW.JsonBDerivedColumn = jsonb_build_object('email', NEW.EmailFlag , 'print', NEW.PrintFlag, 'comment', NEW.SomeOtherField)
    RETURN NEW ;
END ;
$BODY$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS T_Before_Insert_Update_your_table ON your_table ;
CREATE TRIGGER T_Before_Insert_Update_your_table
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF EmailFlag, PrintFlag, SomeOtherField
ON your_table  
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE T_Before_Insert_Update_your_table() ;
```

If your table already exists with rows before you add the new JsonBDerivedColumn column and create the trigger function, you need to populate once the new column for all the existing rows of `your_table`. You can do it by launching a dummy update of the full table and which will trigger the new trigger function for all the existing rows of the table :

```
UPDATE your_table AS t    
   SET EmailFlag = t.EmailFlag
 WHERE TRUE ;
```

But at the end of this story, I'm not sure you will have optimized your SQL queries ... What about [simple index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-types.html) or  [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-multicolumn.html) or [combining multiple indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-bitmap-scans.html) based on the existing columns EmailFlag, PrintFlag, SomeOtherField ?

Comment: Many thanks! I am now just investigating various options, and indeed combining indexes might help too in some cases. However as I work with a real system  with many use cases I do not know yet which approach will be the most effective, before running some experiments.